# Why not Android code style follow google java code style

Tags: java, android, coding-style

I am a java developer and follow Google's java code style for a while, and I am new to Android programming.

I'm interested why Android Java code style is different with Google's Java code style.

For example, in android's field naming convension

> Follow Field Naming Conventions
>
> Non-public, non-static field names start with m. Static field names
>   start with s. Other fields start with a lower case letter. Public
>   static final fields (constants) are ALL_CAPS_WITH_UNDERSCORES.

[http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#follow-field-naming-conventions](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names)

But in Google code style, no *m* or *s* is needed.

> In Google Style special prefixes or suffixes, like those seen in the examples name_, mName, s_name and kName, are not used.

http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s5.1-identifier-names

So I wonder what's the benefit for android has its own naming style.

Why not just follow Google code style, since it's also a Google open source project?

Comment: I had no idea these styles existed.. when programming regular Java and Android I just follow the good old [Java Conventions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334204/official-java-code-guidelines-conventions)... with some updates, like using 140 chars by line instead of 80

Comment: Legacy naming convention? Remember that Android was bought (not made) by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android platform style guidelines were in place before it was developed at Google.